# Can we use OR in a mysql inner join

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
A.`id`
), A.`id` , A.`no` , B.amount, SUM( A.`outward` * A.`price` ) AS total, A.`outward_date`
FROM `outward` A
INNER JOIN franchisees B
INNER JOIN store C
INNER JOIN shoppe D
WHERE B.user_id = C.user_id
AND (C.pos_id = A.no)//(C.pos_id = A.no OR (D.id = A.no)
OR (D.id = A.no)
AND A.outward_date = '2012-02-10'
GROUP BY A.req_id
ORDER BY A.no ASC , A.`d` ASC , B.amount ASC
```

The problem in this query is that the SUM( A.`outward` * A.`price` ) AS total comes differently which is not related to

ouptut

```
id           sum(outward * price)
12021030738-105  485.220000000000
1202104186-104   2504.410000000000
```

output displayed

```
12021030738-105       32557.33
1202104186-104      6307.86
```

i guess the problem is with the OR statement? can anyone find the issue with the query

Comment: http://www.fstadirect.com/onlinehelp/appendices_and_downloads/advanced_search_syntax/logic_operators_and_precedence.htm -> the part about precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. enclose `OR` Conditions in a parenthesis:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT (
    A.`id`
    ), A.`id` , A.`no` , B.amount, SUM( A.`outward` * A.`price` ) AS total, A.`outward_date`
    FROM `outward` A
    INNER JOIN franchisees B
    INNER JOIN store C
    INNER JOIN shoppe D
    WHERE B.user_id = C.user_id
    AND ((C.pos_id = A.no) OR (D.id = A.no))
    AND A.outward_date = '2012-02-10'
    GROUP BY A.req_id
    ORDER BY A.no ASC , A.`d` ASC , B.amount ASC
```